# Is any better way to refactor this code?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code

```
  if(props.plan[plan_id]) {
    if(props.plan[plan_id].number== 0) {
       return null;
    }
    else {
       return 'some value';
    }
  }
```

First of all, I need to check if prop.plan[plan_id] is exist then use its data.
Is any way can make this code more beautiful because I wrote if statement twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, I think maybe instead of using `==`, `===` is better in this case:

```
  if(props.plan[plan_id]) {
    return props.plan[plan_id].number === 0 ? null : 'some value';
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator:

```
if (props.plan[plan_id])
   return (props.plan[plan.id].number == 0) ? null : 'some value';
```

Comment: heh not sure if I would call this "more beautiful" but definitely more terse

Comment: @IsmailBadawi yes I just noticed and edited my answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) can save you from two `if`s as it will terminate at the first statement it can convert to `false` (will not attempt to check the value of `props.plan[plan_id]` unless it existed and the left side evaluated to `true`):

```
return props.plan[plan_id] && props.plan[plan_id].number != 0 ? 'some value' : null;
```

Comment: @Kaiido `0` is falsy, `value == 0` is not.

Comment: how my bad.... sorry, but you forgot the `.value` which is `.number` in OP btw. As it is, it won't ever pass to `'some value'`

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry, I see what you mean. I read the example code the wrong way around. [Now it behaves correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/7z16zzh5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure there is no run-time error, I would do this:

```
return props && props.plan && props.plan[plan_id] ? 'some value' : null
```

You will get `some value` if `props.plan[plan_id]` is not existed or its value is one of: `0`, `undefined`, `null`, or an empty string.